# CSS3 li ul auto size issue

Tags: css

I have created a small drop down menu.. the issue is I don't want it to be a 200px button link unless it needs to in order to make the text fit. example where it says drop downlink  that will be a dynamic link if register has 7 letters but drop downlink has 12 I don't want register to be 200px wide.

```
<ul class="tactical-nav-isolate">
    <li><a href="#">Register</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
    <li class="account-dropdown">
    <a href="#">Dropdown Link<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down account-dropdown-icon"></span></a>
      <ul class="account-dropdown-nav">
        <li><a href="#">My Profile</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">My Account</a></li>        
        <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>




* {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.tactical-nav-isolate {
    text-align: center;
}
.account-dropdown-nav {
    background: #000000;
    text-align: left;
    text-indent: 15px;
}
.tactical-nav-isolate {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 0px;
    border-left: solid 1px #1e2a36;
}
.tactical-nav-isolate > li {
    float: left;
    border-left: solid 1px #1e2a36;
}
.tactical-nav-isolate li:first-child {
    border-left: none;
}
.tactical-nav-isolate a {
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    line-height: 50px;
    width: 200px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.account-dropdown {
    position: relative;

}
.account-dropdown:after {
    font-size: .5em;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 38%;
    right: 12%;
}
.account-dropdown-icon {
    text-indent: 5px;
}
   .account-dropdown-nav {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}
.account-dropdown-nav li {  
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.2);
}
.account-dropdown:hover > .account-dropdown-nav {
    display: block;
    background-image: url(../../media/opacityBG.png);   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not one hundred percent sure what you are asking for, but if your question pertains to having a non-uniform width that fits your  `<a>` tags then all you would need to do is uncomment the following:

```
 .tactical-nav-isolate a {
        //display: block;
    }
```

[look at this](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp) to see the difference between block and inline elements:

Comment: Paradox Where it says dropdown link by glyphicon that will display a username and if the username is longer I would like it to stretch to fit not break the text into a 2nd line

Comment: @paradox, you can comment on your own post to ask for clarification to the [OP](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79804/whats-stackexchange-ese-for-op) if you have any questions that could help you better answer the question.